# Как задать height ttk.Treeview()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Надо чтобы какая-то функция меняла параметр height у ttk.Treeview после его создания, естественно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `widget.config` для изменения параметра виджета

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = len(c)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=[title], height=self.i,
                                 show="headings", selectmode='none')
        self.tree.heading('1', text=title)
        for i in c:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(i,))
        self.tree.pack()
        push = ttk.Button(text='Нажми', command=lambda: self.func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).pack()

    def func(self, *items):
        self.i += len(items)
        for j in items:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(j,))
        self.tree.config(height=self.i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = ['De spasito', 'Spasito', 'Ne Spasito', 'Pasito']
    title = '1'
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Или  при добавлении данных считывайте кол-во записей в виджете и меняйте значения с помощью `ttk.Treeview.get_children()`

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=[title], height=len(c),
                                 show="headings", selectmode='none')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text=title)
        for i in c:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(i,))
        self.tree.pack()
        push = ttk.Button(text='Нажми', command=lambda: self.func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).pack()

    def func(self, *items):
        for j in items:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(j,))
        self.tree.config(height=len(self.tree.get_children()))


c = ['De spasito', 'Spasito', 'Ne Spasito', 'Pasito']
title = '1'
root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```