# Удаление элементов из ttk.Treeview()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Передо мной стоит задача: удалить выборочно элементы ttk.Treeview() или удалить первый. Как мне это реализовать? Любой из этих вариантов подходит.

P.S. Пробовал юзать remove() и delete(), отказывается принимать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавление и обновление высоты из [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817378/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-height-ttk-treeview).

Получаете выбранный объект при помощи `.selection()` и удаляете его при помощи `.delete(items)`.

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = len(c)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=[title], height=self.i,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.heading('1', text=title)
        for i in c:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(i,))
        self.tree.pack()
        push = ttk.Button(text='Нажми', command=lambda: self.func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).pack()
        delete_func = ttk.Button(text='Удалить', command=self.del_func).pack()

    def func(self, *items):
        for j in items:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(j,))
        self.tree.config(height=len(self.tree.get_children()))

    def del_func(self):
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        self.tree.delete(item)
        self.tree.config(height=len(self.tree.get_children()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = ['De spasito', 'Spasito', 'Ne Spasito', 'Pasito']
    title = '1'
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]